# Installed library doesn't show in Reference Manager VS13

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-2013

I've just installed Azure SDK 2.5 and tries to add a reference to Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient in my project in Visual Studio 2013.

I can find the dll installed on my computer but it doesn't show in VS when I open Reference Manager.

Anyone who knows why or how to make it show in Ref Manager?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This seems like an ideal situation for [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/) (which is preinstalled on VS 2013, at least Ultimate). I'd suggest you look into using that.

Comment: I've already tried that way, with no result...

Comment: "No result?" How so?

Comment: Maybe I should have said "same result" ;)
No matter if I install the SDK fron MS website or if I do it from NuGet, I can see that it's installed on the computer (can find the dll in my file system) but it doesn't show in Ref Manager.

Comment: NuGet packages behave a little differently. What do you mean by "ref manager?" The reference list, or an actual dialog?

Comment: The Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient has been deprecated. You should use the latest Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll instead and update your code to suit the newer library. You can obtain Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage from [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/).